# Retrieving Business Unit Name and metadata

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

Is there a way to write a query to get the BU Name and other metadata like description, External Key etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than `AccountID` and `OYBAccountID`, no, there's not a way to retrieve Business Unit info from the System Data Views.

All of the columns available are outlined on the help page: [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).